# Largest possible mean deviation

Tags: statistics

In a data set with 12 numbers, and the lowest and largest numbers can be 0 and 10, what are the numbers in the set to get the largest mean deviation.

The mean deviation is obtained by:

1. Finding the mean of all values
2. Finding the distance of each value from that mean (subtracting the mean from each value, then taking the absolute value)
3. Finding the mean of those distances

Comment: For someone to supply you with the best possible answer, you may want to add a definition of the mean deviation to your question, along with your own progress towards a solution.

Comment: Consider two numbers (e.g. 3 and 5). What does mean deviation do if you move them further apart (say to 2 and 6)?